# Verificar que se cumplen todas las condiciones en js

Tags: javascript, programación-bajo-nivel

Tengo el siguiente grupo de condiciones en Javascript

```
if (rfc_emisor == "si") {
        $("#rfc_emisi").prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        $("#rfc_emino").prop('checked', true);
    }
    if (nombre_agencia == "si") {
        $("#nombre_agensi").prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        $("#nombre_agenno").prop('checked', true);
    }
    if (fecha_operacion == "si") {
        $("#fecha_opersi").prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        $("#fecha_operno").prop('checked', true);
    }
    if (serie_vehiculo == "si") {
        $("#seriesi").prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        $("#serieno").prop('checked', true);
    }
    if (valor_factura == "si") {
        $("#valorfacsi").prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        $("#valorfacno").prop('checked', true);
    }
    if (comprobador == "si") {
        $("#compsi").prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        $("#compno").prop('checked', true);
    }
```

El detalle es que no se como hacer que si una de ellas no se cumple se realice una acción determinada.

Comment: No entiendo muy bien tu pregunta, a que te refieres con si no se cumple una acción?

Te refieres a si entra a algún else acaso?

Comment: Efectivamente, al momento de que entre en un else, que se realice otra acción por ejemplo enviar un mensaje o algo.

Comment: no se entiende bien tu pregunta se mas explicito a lo que te refieres

Comment: Solamente quiero validar que todas las condiciones se cumplan y si no se cumplen mostrar un mensaje

Comment: Usa una variable bandera... es decir inicializas la variable digamos en 0 y si entra en algun else.. va a ser 1 pq cambias su valor... y al final de todas tus validaciones revisas si esa variable esta en 1 o en 0 y si es 1 pues ahi es donde aplica tu msg o lo que requieras hacer....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para dar respuesta a lo que requieres seria de la siguiente manera:

```
var bandera = true;

if (rfc_emisor == "si") {
        $("#rfc_emisi").prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        $("#rfc_emino").prop('checked', true);
        bandera = false;
    }
    if (nombre_agencia == "si") {
        $("#nombre_agensi").prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        $("#nombre_agenno").prop('checked', true);
        bandera = false;
    }
    if (fecha_operacion == "si") {
        $("#fecha_opersi").prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        $("#fecha_operno").prop('checked', true);
        bandera = false;
    }
    if (serie_vehiculo == "si") {
        $("#seriesi").prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        $("#serieno").prop('checked', true);
        bandera = false;
    }
    if (valor_factura == "si") {
        $("#valorfacsi").prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        $("#valorfacno").prop('checked', true);
        bandera = false;
    }
    if (comprobador == "si") {
        $("#compsi").prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        $("#compno").prop('checked', true);
        bandera = false;
    }

   if(bandera == false){
      alert("lo que requieras mostrar cuando no se cumplen todos tus if...");
   }
```

Espero te sea de utilidad. Saludos.

Comment: y por que si se trata de comprobar que todos los if se cumplan, metes a la variable bandera justo despues del else?

Comment: Hola Alfredo buenas tardes, lo hago basandome en el comentario que hace la persona que realiza la pregunta... te lo comparto a continuación: "Solamente quiero validar que todas las condiciones se cumplan y si no se cumplen mostrar un mensaje"

Comment: Efectivamente @JoseReynelChauxPerez muy buena respuesta, me ayudó mucho.

Comment: Como buena practica cambiaria el valor de la bandera

Comment: Vale @Mike acabo de cambiar a valor boolean en lugar de string. Saludos. Muchas gracias por tu apreciación.

Comment: excelente, no pude terminar de editar mi comentario antes de que se bloqueara, pero si, una bandera de preferencia debe ser booleana, tambien como buena practica debe indicar el tipo de dato que se esta buscando, ya sea un caso pesimista o optimista, este caso es pesimista y esta perfecto que pase de true a false

Answer (score 1):

Que te parece cargar a todos tus elementos por medio de su valor, y despúes verificar si falta alguno de ellos, donde todos tendras alguna clase en común.

```
$("#rfc_emisi").prop('checked', rfc_emisor == "si");
$("#nombre_agensi").prop('checked', nombre_agencia == "si");
$("#fecha_opersi").prop('checked', fecha_operacion == "si");
$("#seriesi").prop('checked', serie_vehiculo == "si");
$("#valorfacsi").prop('checked', valor_factura == "si");
$("#compsi").prop('checked', comprobador == "si");

if (!$('.checkbox_check').is(':checked')) {
    MandarAlerta();
}
```